# First cell in range that is not blank and doesn't match cells in another range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get column B to read values in column A that are not blank and not already in the range of B and doesn't match a specific word.

So if A would be:
1: Topic
2: red
3:
4:
5: Topic
6: green
7:
8: Topic
9: orange
10:

Column be would be:
1:red
2:green
3:orange

I've tried using match but I'm not sure how to get it to take both ranges into account. Below is what that looks like. F1 is just "*". Obviously this only get A3. I don't think I can use "AND" with match.

=INDEX(A$3:A$300,MATCH($F$1,A$3:A$300,0))

Comment: If you want a list of topics in column B then the data is probably going to have to start in B2. Typically formulas for a unique list require a cell above them to start the unique check. Alternately, you could have one formula in B1 and another for the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that AND cannot be used. For a unique list with multiple conditions, you need an array formula with nested IF statements.

Put this array formula in B2 and finish with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter. Drag down for additional entries.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$300, MATCH(0, IF(LEN(A$2:A$300), IF(A$2:A$300<>"topic", COUNTIF(B$1:B1, A$2:A$300))), 0)), "")
```

[image]